# What are the different types of names for children?

Tags: scripture, grihya-sutra

I have read somewhere that the grihya sutras mention about the different types of names for naming the children.

I want to know which grihya sutra mentions this and what are the different types mentioned?

Comment: This portion of the book discusses about the naming ceremony of children w.r.t various texts such as Gr̥hya sūtras https://archive.org/details/historyofdharmas029210mbp/page/238/mode/2up?view=theater
 and discussion on day of naming, types of names etc. It's quite detailed, and perhaps may be helpful in resolving your queries on it. There is a whole section of nāmakaraṇa in it.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Bingming ji 